# Kotlin Platform Types and Generics

Tags: kotlin

I am stuck at the last [Kotlin Koans](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/koans.html) task 28 where I get these error messages when I try to call my partitionTo function:

```
Error:(25, 12) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: found: kotlin.Pair<kotlin.Collection<kotlin.String!>, kotlin.Collection<kotlin.String!>> required: kotlin.Pair<kotlin.List<kotlin.String>, kotlin.List<kotlin.String>>
Error:(30, 12) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: found: kotlin.Pair<kotlin.Collection<kotlin.Char!>, kotlin.Collection<kotlin.Char!>> required: kotlin.Pair<kotlin.Set<kotlin.Char>, kotlin.Set<kotlin.Char>>
```

I read that the exclamation mark at the end of a type marks a platform type. But then I would have expected the type `java.lang.String!` and not `kotlin.String!`. Do I have to enforce null checks somewhere? Maybe someone can help me with this last task. I am using IntelliJs Kotlin Plugin version 0.10.195.

This is my code:

```
fun List<String>.partitionWordsAndLines(): Pair<List<String>, List<String>> {
    return partitionTo(ArrayList<String>(), ArrayList<String>()) { s -> !s.contains(" ") }
}
fun Set<Char>.partitionLettersAndOtherSymbols(): Pair<Set<Char>, Set<Char>> {
    return partitionTo(HashSet<Char>(), HashSet<Char>()) { c -> c in 'a'..'z' || c in 'A'..'Z'}
}
inline fun <reified T> Collection<T>.partitionTo(first: MutableCollection<T>, second: MutableCollection<T>, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Pair<Collection<T>, Collection<T>> {
    for (element in this) {
        if (predicate(element)) {
            first.add(element)
        } else {
            second.add(element)
        }
    }
    return Pair(first, second)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, all angle brackets and most of their contents are lost in your example. Could you put them back or share the same code elsewhere (e.g. http://gist.github.com or http://kotlin-demo.jetbrains.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you promised to return a pair of `List`s:

```
fun List<String>.partitionWordsAndLines(): Pair<List<String>, List<String>> {
```

But in fact returned a pair of `Collection`s:

```
inline fun <reified T> Collection<T>.partitionTo(...): Pair<Collection<T>, Collection<T>> {
```

A useful hint from the task:

```
    The signature of the function 'toCollection()' from standard library may help you.
```

See it here: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Snapshots.kt#L207

P.S. Why did you want to use `inline` and `reified` on `partitionTo`?

Comment: I was experimenting with `inline` and `reified` which didn't help obviously :)
But I am still not sure why this doesn't work
`fun <T> Collection<T>.partitionTo(first: MutableCollection<T>, second: MutableCollection<T>, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Pair<MutableCollection<T>, MutableCollection<T>>`
when this works
`fun <T, C: MutableCollection<T>> Collection<T>.partitionTo(first: C, second: C, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Pair<C, C>`
Whats the difference between these two?

Comment: @mellow, when you return `C`, type inference assigns the type of your real argument to `C`, i.e. the actual result is `Pair<ArrayList, ArrayList>`, and this is a subtype of `Pair<List, List>`. When you use `MutableCollection`, all you every get is `MutableCollection`, because it's not a type variable and type inference can't help you, also `MutableCollection` is not a subtype of `List`

Answer (score 1):

Check you return types `partitionWordsAndLines(): **Pair, List>**`, extensions require `List` or `Set` where `partitionTo` returns `Collection`

Here is fixed version

`inline fun <reified T, C: MutableCollection<T>> Collection<T>.partitionTo(first: C, second: C, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Pair<C, C>`